# Using azure search locally

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I am working on a project that uses cosmos db as a database and azure search for searching in cosmos db. Azuse Cosmos DB and Azure search is really expensive so I use my dev cosmos db for development. Thanks Microsoft for the local cosmos db. Is there also a local version of azure search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure search does not support a local version.

If you want to improve it, you could vote this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6760966-provide-a-local-emulator-or-increase-the-number-of).

Besides, as @GauravMantri said, Azure search has a **free** pricing tier, you could use it for **development** purpose. For the pricing tier and limit, refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/search/).

Comment: @JoyWang....You may want to mention that there's "Free" tier of Search Service available that can be used for development purpose only. There's no charge for that.

Comment: @GauravMantri Oh, thanks for reminding, I will update my answer.

Comment: I think the free pricing tier is too limited for the purpose. Example: We have 100+ indices). It would be better if there was an option to use the same API with an emulator running locally just like there are emulators for Compute and Storage.